# django - get max values over several periods

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I just started with django. My Model is very simple and consists of a timestamp and a value (temperature, updated every minute). I would like to retrieve the max value for each day of the past 7 days.

Do I need to query 7 times or is there a 'shortcut'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) and [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=7)

MyModel.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=start_date).extra(select={'day': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('day', 'timestamp')}).values('day').annotate(max_temperature=Max('temperature'))
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe, I just tried that. The result of that query contains datetime objects but how do I access the max values?

Comment: I'm getting an errormessage now: "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'max_temperature' into field. Choices are: id, temperature, timestamp"

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've edited the answer - give it a try once more. Don't forget to import `connection`: `from django.db import connection`.