# How to get the db id/pk of the returned querysets?

Tags: django

I have a model query that returns the max value for each day in the database, but it only returns the date and the count. I'm in need of the id/pk in the database, but i'm not sure how to gather it.

```
from django.db import connection
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

def query(request):
    test = NetworkStats.objects.extra(select={'day': connection.ops.date_trunc_sql(
        'day', 'date')}).values('day').annotate(online=Max('online'))
    for obj in test:
        print(obj)
```

The above code prints out the following:

```
{'day': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=), 'online': 485}
{'day': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=), 'online': 466}
```

models.py:

```
class NetworkStats(models.Model):
    online = models.IntegerField()
    cores = models.IntegerField()
    memory = models.FloatField()
    disk = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

But I specifically need the id/pk of these values returned. How can I achieve this?

So the thought behind the need of this is that i'm querying a value (that's changing periodically during the day) using a task scheduler every 15th second to save that to my database. The reason for that is that I want to grab the max value for each day and then delete all the other records that aren't the max value so my DB doesn't fill up my disk with all this data. Right now i'm looking at 8 GB a day where as I actually only need the Max value for each day and that should be around a few bytes / kb at most.

`test` is a modified version of this [django - get max values over several periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182952/django-get-max-values-over-several-periods)

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the `NetworkStats` model class. Also, if you explain why you are using `.extra` it will be easier to understand what you need to achieve.

Comment: @BradMartsberger Hello! I've updated my post with the model and the thoughts behind why I need this.

Comment: I'd suggest splitting your work into two models - your working table and a table of historical maximums.  That way, every day, you can get the max, put it in the history, then wipe the working table.